# External scripts.js using jquery's AJAX returns Uncaught ReferenceError at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have spent the better half of a day looking for an answer to this problem, I can just not wrap  my head around it. I have an Index.php that requires the head element.
Head element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="requires/style.css" type="text/css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="requires/scripts.js"></script>
   <title>Frontends</title>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="grid-container">

        <div class='header' style="background-color: #0059B3;">
            <a href='index.php'>
                <img src="assets/hhe logo.PNG"/>
            </a>
        </div>
```

This is required into the index.php file, this file looks like so:

```
<?php
require_once 'requires/head.html';
require 'requires/connect.php';
$string = "";
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
    <div class='content' style='border-radius: 4px;'>

        <div class="formcentre">
            <input class="searchform" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Søger så snart du skriver." onkeyup="submitter();" autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>

        <div class='menu' style=' margin-top:10px;'>
            <dl>
                <dt>Tilføj</dt>
                <dd>
                    <a href='opret.php'>Artikel</a><br>
                    <a href="addnew.php">Enhed</a><br>
                    <a href="newscim.php">Kategori</a><br>
                </dd>
                <dt>Slet</dt>
                <dd>
                    <a href="slet.php">Enhed</a><br>
                    <a href="sletkategori.php">Kategori</a>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>

        <table id="results">

        </table>

        <a href="#" class="scrollToTop">⌃</a>

    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="requires/scripts.js"></script>
</body><!--Is opened in the reuired head.html-->
</html><!--Is opened in the reuired head.html-->
```

There is ofcourse a scripts.js file that looks like this:

```
function goBack() {
            window.history.back();
        }

function submitter() {
    var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
    /*AJAX the searchstring*/
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax/searcher.php',
        data: { searchString : search },
        success: function(response){
            $('#results').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
} 
$(document).ready(
function submitter() {
    var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
    /*AJAX the searchstring*/
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax/searcher.php',
        data: { searchString : search },
        success: function(response){
            $('#results').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function(){

//Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
    }
});

//Click event to scroll to top
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
 });

});
```

This all fine and well, I suffer from the problem that I get this specific error when i try to search for anything:

Uncaught ReferenceError: submitter is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (index.php:27)

So the question is: should I not be able to do it this way?

Edit:
I would like to add that, apparently the browser may cache a JS file. So, yeah clear the cache. that's what actually did the trick including point number four on the marked solution. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: whay you have defined `submitter()` 2 times?

Comment: Your JS code is a mess, and you've included it twice, once in the head and again at the end of the body.

Comment: Can you show the index.php file? There should be the problem near line 27.

Comment: @DiabloSteve The problem is in line 27 of the final HTML sent to the browser. OP has posted the PHP source instead, so he is already showing what you're asking for. The issue is caused by a huge syntax error in `script.js`.

Comment: @Chris G, so where is the final HTML line 27? There is a splitted HTML, can you show the line 27? BTW, there is 2 sibmitter definition in the js.

Comment: @DiabloSteve It's the `<input>` line, and the error is caused by `onkeyup="submitter();"` since due to the JS mess, `submitter` doesn't exist.

Comment: First, there should be only 1 "function submitter(){...}", then we may think about this line problem.

Comment: @DiabloSteve You don't say... ;)

Comment: @Chris G, you should add relevant comment then. Search the fault part maybe. :)

Comment: Here's the code you'll want to use: https://jsfiddle.net/ww4Lo6nq/ (remove the `onkeyup` attribute in your HTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, let's do two things:

1. Do not mix JavaScript and jQuery (although both are JavaScripts).
2. Use unobtrusive code.

These are the changes I have done:

1. Remove the `onkeyup` from the element:

   ```
   <input class="searchform" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Søger så snart du skriver." autocomplete="off"/>
   ```
2. Add the event listener using the `document`'s `ready` event:

   ```
   $(function () {
     $("#search").keyup(function () {
       submitter();
     });
   });
   ```

   Still better, you can do it this way:

   ```
   $(function () {
     $("#search").keyup(submitter);
   });
   ```

   Thanks to [Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g).
3. Use a single way:

   ```
   function submitter() {
     $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: 'ajax/searcher.php',
       data: {
         searchString: $("#search").val()
       },
       success: function(response) {
         $('#results').html(response);
       }
     });
     return false;
   }
   ```
4. Remove the duplicate occurrences of `submitter()` function definition. Just have only one inside the `document`'s `ready` event.

Comment: `$("#search").keyup(submitter);`

Comment: I would like to add that, apparently the browser may cache a JS file. So, yeah clear the cache. that's what actually did the trick including point number four on your solution. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @SebastianAndersen Welcome. Have a nice day... Thanks.